# Binding two-way in Vuejs not working on display

Tags: data-binding, laravel-5, vue.js

I have a project in Laravel for backend and VueJs for Front end.

I fetch data with my vueJs object using Api programmed in Laravel. My data is Fetched. In my example i get Article data.

```
 fetchFamily: function(level , id){
        this.$http.get('/api/family/' + id, function (data) {
            var select_zone = 'options' + level
            this.$set(select_zone, data);
        })
        //Fetch Article
        this.$http.get('/api/family/' + id +'/material', function (data) {
            this.$set('materials', data);
        })

    },
    onSelectArticle: function(id){
        var self = this;
        jQuery.each(this.materials,function(idx,dta){
            if(dta.id == id){
                dta.qte = 0
                self.items.push(dta);
                return false;
            }
        });
        $('#myModalArticle').modal('hide');


    }
```

But when i want to initialize the quantity data to 0.

```
 dta.qte = 0
```

I have a problem that in my table i have a input binding to this data.

```
<tr v-for="item in items">
    <td class="hidden-sm"><a  href="/final/doc/{{ $document->id }}/edit"> @{{ item.code }}</a></td>
    <td width="20%"> @{{ item.textes[0].texte }}</td>
    <td>18.00</td>
    <td><input type="text" v-model="item.qte"  ></td>
    <td>@{{ item.code }}</td>
    <td>Colis</td>
    <td>10%</td>
    <td>16.20</td>
    <td>@{{ item.qte * item.prices[0].price }}</td>
    <td>{{ 18 * 40 * 1.17 }}</td>
</tr>
```

And when i am trying to change this value, in my screen the value doesn't change. And in my console when i check the value the value was changed.!!

```
vmApp.items[0].qte
```

Thank you for your Help!

Comment: what does your `data()` method look like initially? is `items` properly initialized as an empty array?

Comment: Yes, i have like that  items : []

Comment: Your issue is likely that you're mutating the data outside of vue, eg in the callback under jquery each(). I haven't looked under the hood but I suspect the iterator iterates a copy of your array so you aren't in fact mutating the object you think, rather the copy. And why do you need jQuery.each() anyway? Why not `for (let idx in this.materials) { ... }` ? This way you are actually iterating on your vue's `this.materials` object, as you likely expected in the first place.